# How to show sublevel sets of a quasiconvex function as its convex inequalities?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to represent the quasiconvex function
 $$f(t)=a e^{-b e^{-c (t-d)}}$$
as a family of convex inequalities to use in its feasible convex programming.

I know that the point of inflection is at $x=d,y=a/e$ and the function is twice differentiable if I'm right. 
And is there any procedure that I can run on any quasiconvex function for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: What can we assume about the signs or ranges of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$?

Comment: I consider all of them are positive ($b\ge c$) and set them as a=0.1,b=3,c=0.09,d=15. Thanks.

Comment: I have doubts about the quasiconvexity of this function, would you confirm by a proof that I am correct?